# React Native Android networking is completely broken

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

When I use Fetch API as they described on their website, this is the error that I get: 

`TypeError: Network request failed
    at xhr.onload (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:5881:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._sendLoad (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19897:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19887:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest._didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19782:6)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19736:105
    at EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:18050:23)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:16698:23)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:16602:8
    at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:16556:1)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:16601:1)`

Here is the code that triggers this error:

```
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/basecomponents.js`)
    .then(myFunction)
    .catch(errorHandler);
```

I googled for solutions and found few topics saying that gzip compression on react native android crashes the app while using Fetch API, so I tried that and nothing happened. Same error.

Then I tried XMLHttpRequest API. Here is the code:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4/* && xhttp.status == 200*/) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText);      
    }    
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", `${baseUrl}/basecomponents.js`, true);
  xhttp.send();
```

And this didn't work too. I got `"Unable to resolve host http://arbormis.loc"` error. So I have no way to make any network requests on android. Please help!

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here? Why are you trying to fetch some external javascript file?

Comment: What is ${baseURL} ? How is it instantiated ?

Comment: @G.Hamaide baseUrl is my local dev machine, http://arbormis.loc, while on production it will be a different url

Comment: @BilalBudhani I'm downloading logic and views from my own server, this enables me to show whatever I want to the end users, update the app as frequently as I want, not go through the app store etc.

Comment: Btw, the same code runs perfectly fine on IOS. It just doesn't work on Android.

Comment: I've tried with RN v0.20 and v0.21, both have this error.